# I have a all the rows with a particular column with lists. Select rows that does not contain atleast one element from the target list

Tags: python, pandas, list, apply

I have a data frame which has rows that contain lists (Lets call B)
I have a target list (let's call A). I want to store all the rows, that does not have at least one common element in B and A.

```
A = [
'IAB24',
'IAB9-WS1',
'IAB9-WS2',
'IAB26-WS1',
'IAB9-9',
'IAB14-WS1',
'IAB14-1',
'IAB19-15',
'IAB25-5',
'IAB25-2',
'IAB19-WS2',
'IAB26',
'IAB25-3',
'IAB7-39']
```

Below is the B Dataframe:

```
URL          Category
google.com  [IAB19, Technology & Computing, 0.878928848558...
youtube.com [IAB25, Non-Standard Content, 0.99999999988656...
facebook.co [IAB14, Society, 0.974491504626058713, IAB14-W...
amazon.com  [IAB22, Shopping, 0.732955918165917875]
wpedia.org  [IAB5, Education, 1.000000000000000000]
```

I want to check if any of the code in A not present in B['Category'], then I would like to store them in a new data frame called C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use set intersection. We want to find rows where the intersection is the empty set.

```
df[[not(bool(set(A) & set(x))) for x in df.Category]]
```

A bit more straight-forward:

```
df[[len(set(A) & set(x)) == 0 for x in df.Category]]
```